# How can I write a C # custom method that takes user input and saves it as a text file and then another method that reads the file?

Tags: c#

Write a program which uses two custom methods:
Custom method 1 should take user input and save it to a text file.
Custom method 2 should open the text file containing the user's input data and display it to the screen.

Your program should not crash if the user is not allowed to save files in the directory.

Your program should not crash if it is not able to open the user file.

I currently have

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter text to save:");
        string textInput = Console.ReadLine();

        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("Final.txt"))
        {
            writer.WriteLine(textInput);
        }

        string line = "";
        using (var sr = new StreamReader("Final.txt"))
        {
            while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The Saved text is:");
                Console.WriteLine(line);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I believe that covers the first two options but I have problems recognizing the other two.

I am completely new to coding and so I am at total odds about what I should do. Any tips would be appreciated.

Regards,

Comment: `I have problems recognizing the other two.` what is the issue you are facing?

Comment: I think you can do it with with FileWatcher event. First write file and then other method will trigger that event.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you don't need to use [`StreamWriter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamwriter?view=netframework-4.7.2), you can simply write text to a file by using [`File.WriteAllText`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.writealltext?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_IO_File_WriteAllText_System_String_System_String_) which solves the issue that you seemed to experience: the file not being closed properly.

---

Secondly, in your shown code you are not handling the possible errors that you are supposed to handle:

1. The user is not allowed to write to or read from the directory specified
2. The file cannot be opened.

If the user is not allowed to write to the file or read from it, a [`System.UnauthorizedAccessException`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.unauthorizedaccessexception?view=netframework-4.7.2) is thrown. If the file cannot be opened, a [`System.IOException`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ioexception?view=netframework-4.7.2) is thrown.

So what we want to do is handle those exceptions by surrounding the call to `File.WriteAllText` with a

```
try
{
    File.WriteAllText(...);
}
catch(UnauthorizedAccessException)
{
    ...
}
catch(IOException)
{
    ...
}
```

and we do the same for `File.ReadAllText` as well.

---

Complete code for your task:

```
private string fileName = "Final.txt";

public void CustomMethod1()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter the text to save: ");
    string textInput = Console.ReadLine();

    try
    {
        File.WriteAllText(this.fileName, textInput);
    }
    catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"You are not allowed to save files in the directory '{this.fileName}'.");
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"The error '{e.Message}' occured while saving the file.");
    }
}

public void CustomMethod2()
{
    if (!File.Exists(this.fileName))
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Cannot find the file '{this.fileName}'.");
    }

    try
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The saved text is: ");
        Console.WriteLine(File.ReadAllText(this.fileName));
    }
    catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"You are not allowed to read files from the directory '{this.fileName}'.");
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"The error '{e.Message}' occured while opening the file.");
    }
}

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Program program = new Program();
    program.CustomMethod1();
    program.CustomMethod2();
}
```